# When to use transaction queues?

Tags: elisp

Is there a reason so few packages seem to use transaction queues (`tq-enqueue` etc.) for communication with external processes? Most of the packages I have looked at seem to prefer the regular filter mechanism.

Comment: I suspect a combination of people just skipping that part of the manual or just reading about filters and transaction queues looking weird and not being powerful/flexible enough.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but the body and title are somewhat different questions here. :-)

Comment: To keep it in line with my sentiment and to answer the titular question: Never. Unless you're maintaining legacy code using it.

Comment: Why never ? (That's all I have to say.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to know about Emacs is that there are a lot of obscure libraries that come with it.  And, far from being a historical oddity, more go into the tree all the time.  Many times these were written for a single use.

There's no single reason such things aren't reused.  Maybe it didn't fit some uses, maybe some authors didn't know of it, etc.  In your case for `tq.el` the answer is the same -- use it if it is a good fit for your problem.  To me it seems a bit under-general; e.g., there's no way to queue a regexp without also sending a string.  Also it's a bit old-fashioned with the "closure" arguments; these are unnecessary now that Emacs has lexical binding.

There's also some library duplication in Emacs.  So for example there are both `ewoc.el` and `tabulated-list.el`, two different ways to accomplish a sort of MVC-ish task.

Comment: Indeed, I had no idea this library existed! Emacs really has too much stuff built-in--the current plan to extract things into ELPA is definitely a good idea.

Comment: Is there any other built-in library providing answer question boundaries to the communication between Emacs and a sub-process like transaction queues? As far as I understand, the default filter functions can be called with arbitrarily sized chunks of the output produced by the sub-process.